# DatagramSocket not receiving / sending to the server in JAR

Tags: java, android, sockets, intellij-idea, udp

I have an Android server that I can connect to from my client in Java using DatagramSocket. It works perfectly fine when I run it from IntelliJ (the data is sent and received to and by the Android server). When I build from IntelliJ to a JAR file, I am unable to sometimes receive packets from the server, and sometimes I am unable to send any packets to the server. I have tried disabling the Firewall as well, even as far as using JLaunch to package the .jar file into an .exe and adding that to the Firewall to allow all incoming / outgoing traffic, but nothing has worked so far. It only works when I run the code through IntelliJ or Eclipse.

I connect to the server by getting the device's IP and the port I have bound the server to.

```
InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(UserInterface.addressTextArea.getText(), PORT);
try {
     serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(null);
     serverSocket.connect(address);
} catch (SocketException | IllegalArgumentException socketException) {
     socketException.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is the code where I receive / send. I send an empty byte just so I can confirm I'm getting the packet on the server (which I do when I run from IntelliJ)

```
serverSocket.send(new DatagramPacket(new byte[0], 0));

// Receive packet from the Android server
byte[] receivedData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
receivedPacket = new DatagramPacket(receivedData, receivedData.length);
serverSocket.receive(receivedPacket);
```

Here is the code on the Android server

```
/* Check if client is connected */
DatagramPacket client = new DatagramPacket(new byte[0], 0);
udpServerSocket.receive(client);

/* Read audioRecorder data and wrap it in a packet for UDP socket to send */
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(
new byte[0],
0,
client.getAddress(),
client.getPort());
udpServerSocket.send(packet));
```

I'd like to be able to just run a .jar file instead of compiling and running from an IDE. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Building from the IDE still builds a jar file.  So there's really no difference.  If your code sometimes sends a packet, the problem is more likely in the network than in your code.

Comment: You mean running from IDE right? Yeah makes sense, but the connection is persistent when running from IDE but building to a .jar makes no attempt at sending or receiving packets at all.

Comment: What IP are you using?  Is the android device connected via wifi, or is it an emulator running on the same device?  That could make a difference.